# How to give second array value to first array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have two php array as below

1) First array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12223
    [1] => 18145

)
```

2) Second array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1808
    [1] => 1801
)
```

I want result like this can you please help me to solve this make sure both array have 100 + value its just example for 2 value

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => 12223
        [1] => 1808
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 18145
        [1] => 1808
    )
Array
    (
        [0] => 18145
        [1] => 1801
    )
Array
    (
        [0] => 12223
        [1] => 1801
    )
```

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: What logic do you want to implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple foreach to create new array

```
$array1 = array(12223,18145);
$array2 = array(1808,1801);
$new_array = array();
foreach($array1 as $value)
{
    foreach($array2 as $value2)
    {
        $tmparray=array($value,$value2);
        $new_array[]=$tmparray;    
    }

}
print_r($new_array);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/DjLeQ)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<?php

$arr1 = array(12223, 18145);
$arr2 = array(1808);

$arrs = array_chunk($arr1, 1);

$arrs[0][1] = $arr2[0];
$arrs[1][1] = $arr2[0];

var_dump($arrs);
?>
```

will solve the problem exactly as described (resulting in 2 arrays):

```
array(2) { 
  [0]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> int(12223) 
    [1]=> int(1808) 
  } 
  [1]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> int(18145) 
    [1]=> int(1808) 
  } 
}
```

N.B. I'm guessing you may actually want a slightly more generic solution, but you haven't given any particular rules or algorithm by which to achieve that, so this answer is a literal solution to your exact specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, definetly with a for each loop:

for each (integer i in array)

check every value if its bigger than 100 and if not you can set it to 100 etc.

lg!